# Consuming a web service on a .net smart device application

Tags: .net, sockets, device-emulation

I am trying to consume a web service locally on a .net smart device application and getting this error:-

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Probable causes:

1. Your emulator do not allow the connection
2. The server is really not responding
3. A firewall prevents the connection